# How to sum certain values in a pandas column DataFrame in a specific date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame that looks something like this: 
df =

```
    UPC   Unit_Sales  Price   Price_Change  Date 
 0   22          15    1.99         NaN     2017-10-10
 1   22          7     2.19         True    2017-10-12
 2   22          6     2.19         NaN     2017-10-13
 3   22          7     1.99         True    2017-10-16
 4   22          4     1.99         NaN     2017-10-17
 5   35          15    3.99         NaN     2017-10-09
 6   35          17    3.99         NaN     2017-10-11
 7   35          5     4.29         True    2017-10-13
 8   35          8     4.29         NaN     2017-10-15
 9   35          2     4.29         NaN     2017-10-15
```

Basically I am trying to record how the sales of a product(UPC) reacted once the price changed for the following 7 days. I want to create a new column ['Reaction'] which records the sum of the unit sales from the day of price change, and 7 days forward. Keep in mind, sometimes a UPC has more than 2 price changes, so I want a different sum for each price change. 
So I want to see this:

```
    UPC   Unit_Sales  Price   Price_Change  Date        Reaction
 0   22          15    1.99         NaN     2017-10-10      NaN
 1   22          7     2.19         True    2017-10-12      13   
 2   22          6     2.19         NaN     2017-10-13      NaN
 3   22          7     1.99         True    2017-10-16      11
 4   22          4     1.99         NaN     2017-10-19      NaN
 5   35          15    3.99         NaN     2017-10-09      NaN
 6   35          17    3.99         NaN     2017-10-11      NaN
 7   35          5     4.29         True    2017-10-13       15
 8   35          8     4.29         NaN     2017-10-15      NaN
 9   35          2     4.29         NaN     2017-10-18      NaN
```

What is difficult is how the dates are set up in my data. Sometimes (like for UPC 35) the dates don't range past 7 days. So I would want it to default to the next nearest date, or however many dates there are (if there are less than 7 days).

Here's what I've tried: 
I set the date to a datetime and I'm thinking of counting days by .days method. 
This is how I'm thinking of setting a code up (rough draft):

```
  x = df.loc[df['Price_Change'] == 'True']
  for x in df: 
       df['Reaction'] = sum(df.Unit_Sales[1day :8days])
```

Is there an easier way to do this, maybe without a for loop?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly how you get your expected output?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for not being more clear. 24 is calculated by taking the sum of unit sales from row 1 to row 4, which is within the 7 day date range I wanted. Similarly, 15 is calculated by adding unit sales of rows 7 to 9.

Comment: im calculating the sum of unit sales for each UPC after there was a price change, for a window of at most 7 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `ffill` with `groupby`

```
df.loc[df.Price_Change==True,'Reaction']=df.groupby('UPC').apply(lambda x : (x['Price_Change'].ffill()*x['Unit_Sales']).sum()).values
df
Out[807]: 
   UPC  Unit_Sales  Price Price_Change        Date  Reaction
0   22          15   1.99          NaN  2017-10-10       NaN
1   22           7   2.19         True  2017-10-12      24.0
2   22           6   2.19          NaN  2017-10-13       NaN
3   22           7   2.19          NaN  2017-10-16       NaN
4   22           4   2.19          NaN  2017-10-17       NaN
5   35          15   3.99          NaN  2017-10-09       NaN
6   35          17   3.99          NaN  2017-10-11       NaN
7   35           5   4.29         True  2017-10-13      15.0
8   35           8   4.29          NaN  2017-10-15       NaN
9   35           2   4.29          NaN  2017-10-15       NaN
```

Update

```
df['New']=df.groupby('UPC').apply(lambda x : x['Price_Change']==True).cumsum().values

v1=df.groupby(['UPC','New']).apply(lambda x : (x['Price_Change'].ffill()*x['Unit_Sales']).sum())

df=df.merge(v1.reset_index())

df[0]=df[0].mask(df['Price_Change']!=True)
df
Out[927]: 
   UPC  Unit_Sales  Price Price_Change        Date  New     0
0   22          15   1.99          NaN  2017-10-10    0   NaN
1   22           7   2.19         True  2017-10-12    1  13.0
2   22           6   2.19          NaN  2017-10-13    1   NaN
3   22           7   1.99         True  2017-10-16    2  11.0
4   22           4   1.99          NaN  2017-10-17    2   NaN
5   35          15   3.99          NaN  2017-10-09    2   NaN
6   35          17   3.99          NaN  2017-10-11    2   NaN
7   35           5   4.29         True  2017-10-13    3  15.0
8   35           8   4.29          NaN  2017-10-15    3   NaN
9   35           2   4.29          NaN  2017-10-15    3   NaN
```

Comment: Nice one-liner! Note that this will add up *all* unit sales following the price change, not just (up to) the next 7 days after a price change.

Comment: Oh this is great! Right @Peter I noticed that, thanks. But this is a good start.

Comment: Also I tried this on my DataFrame and im getting this error:

Comment: 'TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')'

Comment: Not quite sure what that means

Comment: @Hana Try , add df['Price_Change']=df['Price_Change'].replace('True',True) ?

Comment: Ah, so that line took care of that error, thank you!. However, nwo its giving me this error: 'ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable' @Wen

Comment: @Hana So you may have Two price_change within in one UPC?

Comment: @Wen, oh yea that is definitely possible. Is there a way to start a new sum for a new price change for one UPC ?

Comment: Let me modify my answer , or maybe you can include that situation

Comment: @Wen I can't seem to figure it out, let me know if you can help with this. Keep getting the same error above when I tried to modify the code

Comment: @Hana it is better for you to include the special case (More than two True for one UTC) in your sample data

Comment: I edited my question! I made the first UPC have 2 price changes. So I want to see a new sum for each price change @Wen

Comment: @Wen awesome! Thank you! This is perfect. Would you mind quickly explaining what the 'New' column is for?

Comment: @Hana this cause you have subgroup(depends on how many true you have within one UPC) with each group UPC, The New para here , is to setting the subgroup Id :-)

Comment: I see! Thank you for helping me understand this @Wen! Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Hana yw：-） happy coding